# How to not set an Icon for the last form item inside this code?

Tags: react-native, redux-form, react-native-ios, native-base

I am using Redux-form for form validation. Inside the renderinput we have many inputs and each of them has it's own Icon however we need to use the field with date2 input.name without icon. I set it null, undefined, false while unfortunately   no one of those worked. Here is the code:

```
renderInput({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) {
    return (
      <Item error={error && touched} style={styles.item}>

<Icon  style={styles.icon} active name={input.name === "card" ? "card" : input.name=== "date" ? "calendar": input.name === "csv" ? "unlock" : input.name === "name" ?"contact":undefined} />
                <Input style={styles.input}
                    ref={c => (this.textInput = c)}
                    placeholder={input.name === "card" ? "Card Number": input.name==="date"?"MM":input.name==="date2"?"YY":input.name==="csv"?"CSV": "Name"}
            placeholderTextColor="#0dc49d"
                    secureTextEntry={input.name === "csv" ? true : false}
                    {...input}
                />
            </Item>

    );
  }
```

For the last

```
 <Icon  style={styles.icon} active name={input.name === "card" ? "card" : input.name=== "date" ? "calendar": input.name === "csv" ? "unlock" : input.name === "name" ?"contact":undefined} />
```

else  I need it without icon. Here undefined was used which is also not working as it's mentioned above. How can I overcome this challenge?

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally render the icon:

```
renderInput({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) {
    const renderIcon = (input.name === "card" || input.name=== "date" || input.name === "csv" || input.name === "name")
    return (
      <Item error={error && touched} style={styles.item}>
                { 
                  renderIcon && 
                  <Icon  style={styles.icon} active name={input.name === "card" ? "card" : input.name=== "date" ? "calendar": input.name === "csv" ? "unlock" : input.name === "name" ?"contact":undefined} /> 
                }
                <Input style={styles.input}
                    ref={c => (this.textInput = c)}
                    placeholder={input.name === "card" ? "Card Number": input.name==="date"?"MM":input.name==="date2"?"YY":input.name==="csv"?"CSV": "Name"}
            placeholderTextColor="#0dc49d"
                    secureTextEntry={input.name === "csv" ? true : false}
                    {...input}
                />
            </Item>

    );
  }
```